# Uploadify causes Safari to crash when alerting in javascript

Tags: safari, alert, uploadify

I am having an issue with Uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/) in Safari where that when a javascript alert is called is causes the browser to crash/freeze.

You can replicate this problem by simply going to: http://www.uploadify.com/demos/ select a file to upload and whilst this file is uploading, select the same file again to upload - this will cause Uploadify to throw an alert saying that the file is already in the queue and then the browser will freeze and become completely unresponsive.

I am just wondering if anyone else who has encountered this problem find a workaround or explanation to why this happens?

Cheers,

Danny